# How to add category products in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

There is no any product category listed. How to add categories to the list.

[image: Empty list]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create your **categories under the default category.**
Here You can **drag and drop** your categories to default category.
Because **default category is root category.**

Make sure that you have created some products.

Then you can select a particular category and Please click on Reset Filter on the right and all products will show up.
After that, you can select the products you want to add and click Save Category.

Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please click on Reset Filter on the right and all products will show up.

After that, you can select the products you want to add and click Save Category.

Comment: There is no sample data. So can't we add them newly.

Comment: You can add new products via Catalog > Manage Products > Add Product